# Iterate through corresponding Pandas columns and then split them

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to help a friend, he has an excel file, where the first row is the product name, and then this product row has several columns, one of them being product images (in URLs) separated by commas. What he asked me to help him do is duplicate the product row, with only the "Product" and "Image" categories, and have only one image URL per row. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks for your question! Would it be possible for you to post the first few rows of this dataframe? It's hard to help without a reproducible example

Comment: Please, could you write some code example about you expect as the output of your issue?

Comment: @CarMoreno

Quick example of what they should look like:

Before/after: https://imgur.com/a/s5d9RQb

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein Quick example of what they should look like: Before/after: imgur.com/a/s5d9RQb

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean it's like this:

```
[Column A]          [Column B]
MyProduct1          url1,url2,url3
MyProduct2          url4,url5,url6,url7
```

And you want

```
MyProduct1, url1
MyProduct1, url2
MyProduct1, url3
MyProduct2, url4 
MyProduct3, url5
```

etc etc

If this is a one off then you could  do this

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7

If not a one-off then you could familiarise your self with left,right,mid functions and find to help text string manipulations...

Then you would need to write some code that ran 2 loops. The inner loop iterates over columns that aren't empty (the ones with URLs) for a given row. The outer loop iterates over the product rows...

```
   myRow = 2
   do until sheets("InputSheetName").cells(myRow,1)=""

       myCol = 2
       do until Sheets("InputSheetName").cells(myRow,myCol)=""
           Sheets("OutputSheet").cells(newRow,2) = Sheets("InputSheetName").cells(myRow,myCol)        
           newRow = newRow+1
           myCol = myCol +1 
       loop
   
       myRow=myRow+1
   loop
```

Comment: Exactly like you describe in the beggining, but the link you sent isn't exactly that, even though it is a one off. I'll try to implement your logic! Thanks for your time

Comment: @Gabriel ok click this as the answer then